# encounter KeyError problem when doing opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently leaning OpenCV and tryna do face recognition by myself.

I watched several videos on youtube and finally write it to code, but every time when I running the programme it always reveals

```py
print(labels[id_])
KeyError: 1
```

I searched how to solve the Keyerror problems for a few days, but I cannot really find an answer.

here is the code

```py
labels = {"person_name": 1}

with open("labels.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    og_labels = pickle.load(f)

labels = {v: k for k, v in og_labels.items()}

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        id_,conf = recognizer.predict(roi_gray)
        if conf >= 4 and conf <= 85:

            if id_ == 1:
                print(id_)
            print(labels[id_])
```

I don't know if it's a problem here, because I have a face-train file (can run). If there is no problem with the above code, I think it should be a face-train problem. 
I can provide more code. 
Of course, if you have related videos, you can also recommend it to me.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You are overwriting `labels = {"person_name": 1}` with `labels = {v: k for k, v in og_labels.items()}`. What's the purpose of `labels = {"person_name": 1}`?
2. You are trying to access `labels[1]`, which is different from `labels['1']`. Why don't you go ahead and print/`pprint` the contents of `labels` before `print(labels[id_])` and see what the actual keys are?